# Possible to execute script when loading local html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am clicking on a link and loading in an html file which consist of:

```
<div id="galleryPage">
    <p>Hello2</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("hellosdsd");
</script>
```

I then add this into a div on my page and it looks like:

[image]

the script never executes...

What am I missing?

Loading the html like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".link").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const url = event.target.dataset["url"];

        get_html_file(`./Pages/${url}/`, (data) => {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = data;
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function get_html_file(path, success, errorCallback) {
    fetch(path)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
            }
            return response.text();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            if (success) success(data);
            // document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (errorCallback) errorCallback(error);
            console.error(
                "There has been a problem with your fetch operation:",
                error
            );
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, modifying `innerHTML` won't evaluate the script tags it inserts.

You might want to do something like

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("#container script")].forEach(script => {
  if(script.dataset.evaluated) return;  // If already evaluated, skip
  eval(script.innerText);
  script.dataset.evaluated = 1;  // Mark as evaluated
});
```

after you load in the new HTML.

You could also do e.g. `script.parentNode.removeChild(script)` instead of the dataset trick, but this is more useful for debugging.

Comment: Thin is I was trying to keep the script to the respektive file and handle the execution like that. If this is the only way then Im thinking maybe moving the script to a .js file and inserting it in the success function.

Comment: You can keep the script in the other file, that's fine. The snippet above will just make sure that the scripts are executed too, as they won't be otherwise.

Comment: I added it in the success function and it worked. reading up on Eval: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Thx!

Comment: just curious. I was testing and moving my script into a file but loading it in the same file like: 

``<div id="galleryPage">
    <p>Hello3</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script> ```

Then it did not load. If I wanted to do this approach what would I need to change?

Comment: You'd need to load that test.js with yet another request, then evaluate that code.